# como hacer un slider multi item con angular y bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, angular, slider

Estoy haciendo un slider multi item con angular y bootstrap, actualmente lo tengo como muestro en el código pero lo veo demasiado inefciente, es decir, tengo demasiado código repetido, como podría hacer para mejorarlo? antes de esto itente usar el de ngx-bootstrap y no pude hacerlo funcionar por mas que instale todas las dependencias que necesita. Aquí dejo el código de lo que tengo en este momento funcionand:

```js
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/slider/4.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="">
                  <h4>precio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <h4>Ubicacion</h4>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="">
                  <h4>precio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <h4>Ubicacion</h4>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="">
                  <h4>precio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <h4>Ubicacion</h4>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/slider/4.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="">
                  <h4>precio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <h4>Ubicacion</h4>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="">
                  <h4>precio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <h4>Ubicacion</h4>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="">
                  <h4>precio</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <h4>Ubicacion</h4>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nota. no se mucho de javascript, por eso no me he atrevido a empezar uno desde cero ya que debo tenerlo lo más pronto posible.

Comment: No entiendo nada tu código. Por qué estas usando tantos modals? Peor aún con el mismo ID, no entiendo bien dónde está el error ni que estás buscando hacer

Comment: Precisamente ese es mi problema amigo. Veo que estoy repitiendo demasiado código, no he podido lograr optimizar ese slider para no tener tantos items, quiero que vayan pasando de 3 en 3, y que al hacer click en el botón "ver detalles" se abra el modal, por eso tengo un modal para cada botón, pero se que debe haber una forma de mejorar todo eso pero no lo he logrado.